# How can i use php code in html code in netbeans 8.0.1?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, netbeans

I can create a new php project but i want to create i created html5 project and inside i want to use also php code.

Beside download and using netbeans i also downloaded and using xampp.
After running xampp i clicked start on apache.

So now to browse to my testing site i'm going to:

```
http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/index.html
```

It's a free template i downloaded just for the testing.
And the page in my site that i'm trying to use php in html file is:

```
http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/images%20slideshow.html
```

The slideshow.html file content looks like:

```
<?php 
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$) |(\.Gif$)"; //valid image extensions 
$files = array(); 
$curimage=0; 
if($handle = opendir($"http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files")) { 
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
        if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image 
            //Output it as a JavaScript array element 
            $files[] = $file; 
            $curimage++; 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
} 
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    #Timer_Countdown{
    background:black;
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
  </style>

      <script type = "text/javascript">

          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

//$json = json_encode($files);
//json = <?php echo $json; ?>
//var images = JSON.parse(json);
//var images = <?=json_encode($files)?>;
var images = [];
var x = -1; 
var swap_hours = 0;
var swap_minutes = 0;
var swap_seconds = 5;

var down_counter_hours;
var down_counter_minutes;
var down_counter_seconds;

function initTimer() {

    down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
    down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
    down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    counter = setInterval(switcher, 1000);
}

function restartCounter() {
        down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
        down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
        down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
}

function switcher() {
    down_counter_seconds--;
    if (down_counter_hours <= 0 && down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_seconds <= 0) {
        swapColor();
        restartCounter();
    }
    if (down_counter_seconds <= 0 && down_counter_minutes > 0) {
        down_counter_seconds = 60;
        down_counter_minutes--;
    }
    if (down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_hours > 0) {
        down_counter_minutes = 60;
        down_counter_hours--;
    }

    document.getElementById("Timer_Countdown").innerText =        down_counter_hours+":"+down_counter_minutes+":"+down_counter_seconds;
}

function swapColor() {
    displayNextImage();
}

      </script>
      <div id="div_hours" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_minutes" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_seconds" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_switcher" class="div_box"></div>
   </head>

   <body onload = "initTimer()">
       <div id="Timer_Countdown">&nbsp;</div>
       <img id="img" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000005.Gif">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage(); restartCounter()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage(); restartCounter()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

At the top i have a php code starting with `<?php` and ending with `?>`

But netbeans display near the line on the left: `<?php` the error:

> Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML.
>   (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)

I don't want to create php project but using html5 project and using php code also.
So now i think the xampp should come in place and the netbeans should use it's .htaccess that was created automatic once i installed xampp.

Is there any way to use PHP code inside HTML5 project in netbeans 8.0.1 ?

And i'm doing it all local for now for the testing.

Comment: Unless instructed otherwise, html pages wont be interpreted by the php parser, so start by changing the file extension from `.html` to `.php`

Comment: But later on if i will upload my site and the index file will be index.php with html and php codes inside it will still act like index.html ? I mean what is the difference between index.html and index.php ? The only difference is that in index.php i can also use php code with html ?